# how to copy files and folders from docker context to images?

Tags: docker

I have a `rocker/tidyverse:4.2.0` image which I'm using to create an image for myself. I need folders and files, but it's not showing up in the home folder. What am I doing wrong?

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse:4.2.0

RUN mkdir -p $HOME/rstudio/R_scripts
WORKDIR $HOME/rstudio/R_scripts
COPY ./R_scripts/* $HOME/rstudio/R_scripts/
COPY ./R_scripts/.Rprofile $HOME/rstudio/.Rprofile
RUN ls -l $HOME/rstudio
```

And this is how I run it.

```
docker run -it --rm -d -p 8787:8787 -e PASSWORD=rstudio --name rstudio-server -v /mnt/c/Users/test/sources:/home/rstudio/repos --net=host rstudio-server:4.2.0
```

When I check in the home folder, I can't find the folders I copied. `R_scripts` folder is in the same folder which contains `Dockerfile`

Comment: The main reason I'm asking questions on SO is to learn. If one doesn't like the question and votes to close, it'd be nice and important for me to know why so that I can do better in asking questions. Right now, I can't tell why it is voted to close.

Comment: Which folder are you looking in; how are you looking there?  (In many base images `$HOME` is undefined and you might find the content you're looking for in `/rstudio` under the container filesystem root.  Also note that `WORKDIR` creates the directory if it doesn't exist so you don't need to `RUN mkdir` the same directory first.)

Comment: Oh, I see. Now that explains a whole lot. It was copied in `/rstudio`. I had also tried `/home/rstudio` but didn't work either. I just realized that I hadn't created a directory to copy to. Your answer helped me a lot. As you can imagine, this is something I'm learning and doing it for the first time. It's very encouraging and fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker images tend to not have "users" or "home directories" in a way you might think about them in a typical Linux system.  This also means environment variables like `$HOME` often just aren't defined.

This means that when you try to set the current container directory

```bash
WORKDIR $HOME/rstudio/R_scripts
```

since `$HOME` is empty, the files just end up in a `/rstudio` directory in the root of the container filesystem.  (And this might be okay!)

Style-wise, it's worth remembering that the right-hand side of `COPY` can be a relative path relative to the current `WORKDIR`, and that `WORKDIR` and `COPY` will create directories if they don't already exist.  This means you don't usually need to `RUN mkdir`, and you don't usually need to repeat the full container path.  Here I might write

```bash
FROM rocker/tidyverse:4.2.0

WORKDIR /rstudio/R_scripts      # without $HOME, creates the directory
COPY ./R_scripts/* ./           # ./ is WORKDIR
COPY ./R_scripts/.Rprofile ../  # ../ is WORKDIR's parent
# RUN ls -l /rstudio            # invisible using BuildKit backend by default
```

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer. This is extremely helpful. I'm sure it'll be helpful to novice docker users and learners. Thank you for your time and contribution.